# jQuery string Comparison?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm comparing two dates and my code goes like this.

```
jQuery('.newAppointment a.ui-state-default').click(function() {
  var date = jQuery(this).parent().attr('title');
 var d = jQuery.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy',date.toString());
  alert(d);
  var today = new Date;
  var t = jQuery.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy',today.toString() );
  alert(t)
  if(t > d){
  url = "/users/" + user_id + "/events/new?type=Surgery"+"&day=" + escape(date);;
  window.location = url;
  }else{
    alert("you cannot add appointment to past dates");
  }
});
```

but am getting error in firebug.
uncaught exception: Missing number at position 0
can anyone tell me where I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Can Firebug tell you which line the error happens on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/parseDate):

> **parseDate(format, value, settings)**
>   [...]
>   A number of exceptions may be thrown:
>
> - 'Missing number at position nn' if format indicated a numeric value that is not then found

So your error is coming from jQuery-UI. The format you get from [`date.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString) depends on the browser and the locale, there's no reason to expect it always be `dd/mm/yy` and in your case, it isn't.

Your `date` is already a string and in a known format (presumably `dd/mm/yy`) so you should be able to do this:

```
var d = jQuery.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', date);
```

to get a Date. Then you can get `today` with just:

```
var today = new Date;
```

and compare them directly:

```
if(today > d)
```

If you want to throw away the hours, minutes, and seconds then:

```
var now   = new Date;
// Or set milliseconds, seconds, minutes, and hours to zero.
var today = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate());
if(today > d)
```

Answer (score 0):

may be there is some problem with parseDate()
You can compare the dates just by using just

```
if (today > date){...}
```

Comment: date objects can be directly compared

Comment: Ya i tried it but everytime its going into else part.My code goes like this:
jQuery('.newAppointment a.ui-state-default').click(function() {
      var date = jQuery(this).parent().attr('title');
      var today = new Date();
      if(today > date){
      url = "/users/" + user_id + "/events/new?type=Surgery"+"&day=" + escape(date);;
      window.location = url;
      }else{
        alert("you cannot add appointment to past dates");
      }
    });